# Setting up links in Codeigniter

Tags: hyperlink, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to make a simple navigation menu in Codeigniter 2.0 and cant figure out how to make links to my other views.

```
<ul>
 <li>About</li>
 <li>Links</li>
</ul>
```

I have My Views coded. They are: about and links

How do I set up the links in my controller? How do I set up the nav links in my view?

Answer (score 1):

Use anchor. For example:

```
echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', 'title="News title"');
```

Would produce: `<a href="http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123" title="News title">My News</a>`

You need the URL helper for this `$this->load->helper('url');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use CI URL Helper : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

They have explained basic examples as well.